# Gawk "system" call. Run external program in several instances

Tags: system, gawk

I am using Gawk on a MAC based UNIX.  I have a "system" call that runs a program.  As I have understood things, the program waits for the external program before going on to the next line.  I would like to start several instances of the external program, wait for them all to finish, "cat" the results and then continue with the Gawk program.  The value in this is to use all the processors on a MAC Pro machine. It takes days to run now and running the external program in several instances would greatly help.  Thank You in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

system call to bash script that ran various programs in the background.  Used the bash script "wait" command to make sure the programs were finished before returning to the GAWK program.  That worked.
Got the idea from the son of a friend. Very helpful.

Ellis